# Domain User cannot print some PDF files

Tags: terminal-server, network-printer, adobe-reader

I have a strange issue where a domain user cannot print some PDF files on a terminal server.

The Xerox printer reports an "incorrect tray" error.

The same PDF files can be printed ok from the terminal server while logged in as Administrator.

Using Adobe Reader X on Windows Server 2008 SP2.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Adobe Reader, or security on the domain user account.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you ruled out something in the users profile?  Can you temporarily remove the users profile, and have them try again?  Does this happen with a brand new user with a clean profile?

Comment: The PDF file prints ok from another domain user account. Could it be saved Adobe Reader preferences under the affected domain user's profile?

Comment: Maybe Adobe Reader settings, maybe the per-user printer settings for your Xerox.  It is tricky to say.

Comment: Re-creating the user's Windows profile did the trick. Issue resolved.

Comment: @Ash you should post it as an answer an accept it. (When you can, if you can't already.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-creating the user's Windows profile did the trick. Issue resolved.
I'm assuming corrupt or incorrect files under the user's AppData folder.